# Faster way to concurrently insert data into MySQL

Tags: mysql, performance, insert, parallel-processing

I have a parallel process with about 64 children that each need to insert data into a landing table.  I am currently using a MySQL MyISAM engine, and I disable keys before and after inserts.

However, this seems to be a huge bottleneck in my process.  I believe MySQL is table locking for each insert and so processes are constantly waiting to write.

The inserts are independent and there is no danger of conflicting inserts.  This also does not need transactions or anything of that nature.

Is there a different engine, or ways to improve the insert/write performance of MySQL?

I have thought about instantiating a table for each process, but this would make the code more complex, and that is not really my style....

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

As documented under [`INSERT DELAYED` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert-delayed.html):

> The `DELAYED` option for the `INSERT` statement is a MySQL extension to standard SQL that is very useful if you have clients that cannot or need not wait for the `INSERT` to complete.
>
> `[ deletia ]`
>
> Another major benefit of using `INSERT DELAYED` is that inserts from many clients are bundled together and written in one block. This is much faster than performing many separate inserts.

Comment: yes, I was thinking about this, but my concern is that the processing machine and the Server are the same machine.  When using Insert Delayed, where exactly does MySQL hold the data? RAM, SWAP, disk?  I run pretty close to RAM limit already with the processing children...

THANKS!

Comment: @user1459544: "*The queued rows are held only in memory until they are inserted into the table.*" -- of course, the O/S will swap to virtual memory as required - but if you're low on RAM, it's probably worth investing in some more.

Comment: I think at 256GB this machine is tapped, but lets give it a go and I will let you know how it turns out.  Perhaps if it can get into the DB faster my children will release their RAM resources faster and good times for all.

Comment: @user1459544: Sounds like it might be time to consider moving the MySQL server onto another machine.

Comment: @user1459544: Sounds like it might be time to consider moving management (or yourself) into another job.  ;)

Answer (score 2):

MyISAM does indeed lock the tables when inserting, updating or deleting. InnoDB allows transaction and row-based locks.

You can also look into [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) which is faster for bulk inserts.

Comment: InnoDB will still perform a next-row lock, release of which other inserts will have to wait upon.  Sadly `LOAD DATA INFILE` will also not be much use here, as there is no "bulk insert" but rather numerous individual inserts from different clients.

Comment: I could pipe the inserts to text, perhaps even using cat to create a single large file, but this is not optimal IMO, as it is adding more layers of processing.  I could use it as a last resort, but I was hoping there are somethings I could tweak with MySQL to avoid extra steps... or having 64 children trying to write out simultaneously...

Comment: Maybe you could create tables for each process and merge into the main table once all children have completed?